# How to run an application remotely while using a server's resources

Tags: vb.net, email, windows-10, windows-server-2016

I thought this would be a simple task but found I was very wrong apparently. We have a working application that resides in a Windows Server 2016 system This app needs to be triggered remotely by a general user who clicks on a shortcut pointed to the .exe on the server. The problem is that the app needs to be able to run using the server's resources so that an email can be sent (only servers are capable of sending emails).

It seems that the app runs with the user's resources so the email never gets sent. I'm not sure if I need to add some type of scripting (VB.Net) or if I need to configure the .exe/server to enable this function. This works when a user with Admin rights runs the app but we need a regular User to be able to do the same. I have tried using PsExec but still had the same problem. (The user is using Windows 10)

Does anyone have any ideas that can make this happen?

This is the code we're using for the mail function:

```
                Dim client As New SmtpClient()
                Dim mail As New MailMessage()
                mail.From = New MailAddress("email@email.com")
                client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")

                mail.[To].Add("email@email.com")
                mail.[To].Add("email@email.com")

                'set the content
                mail.Subject = "Subject: " & Date.Now
                mail.Body = "Body: " & Date.Now  

                client.Host = "host.host.host.com"
                client.Port = "25"
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = True 

                Try                   
                    client.Send(mail)
                Catch exc As Exception 

                Finally
                    mail = Nothing
                    client = Nothing
                End Try                

        Catch ex As Exception
            '   MsgBox("Error, DB Open " & ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: Without the code of the app it´s impossible to tell what it´s doing

Comment: The problem isn't with the code. The email send for Admins but we need non-Admins to be able to send as well. I've added the mail script to the OP

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `resources`? Dou you have any logs from the smtp server?
Shot in the dark: `client.UseDefaultCredentials = True` takes the credentials of the current logged in user according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials?view=netcore-3.1). Try set it to false

Comment: I say "resources" to mean the app needs to run from the server and not from the user's PC. No logs because the function doesn't run the mail script unless an admin

Comment: How are users calling this app from the shortcut? what does the `shortcut` in this case do? This seems more of a remote execution question rather than a VB.NET question

Comment: Exactly, the code works fine. But when the user clicks a shortcut that points to a .exe file located on a remote server it uses the "user's" local resources (Operating system, CPU memory, etc). In this case, I need the app to run using server's operating system/resources...hope that makes sense